# Rules for Profiles

Tags: discussion, profile-page, rules, moderator-faq

Are there any rules concerning what I can put in my profile?

[Return to Stack Exchange Moderator FAQ](/q/118972/350567)

Comment: see also: [Is spam in the “about me” field a reason to worry?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105218/165773)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Generally speaking, your profile is (to an extent) fair game, as it is a reflection of you as a person, not the site as a whole.

[Self-promotion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31448/how-much-advertising-is-allowed-on-userinfo-pages/31478#31478), your [e-mail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23351/can-i-give-out-my-email-here/23356#23356) address, humor, (if you know HTML) imagery and even the [f-bomb](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-is-the-f-word-still-allowed-in-profiles/31209#31209) are allowed there.

There are reasonable limitations for all of those, but generally speaking, unless you're a hard-core spammer or you put something *truly* offensive / crazy in there (like hate speech or pornography), you'll be OK.

Also, understand that all links are no-followed, so SO doesn't actually give you Google Juice from your profile.

Comment: "Introducing new Google Juice (beta)!  Now you can get your daily allowance of 1-10 of 1,500 recommended minerals in 0.34 seconds!  Enjoy delicious flavors such as Berry Page, Sergey Brine, or the newest flavor, Better Than Apple!  You have 10 invitations to try Google Juice (beta) remaining."

Comment: Your home page is not nofollowed once you reach 2000 rep, though. (Neither are internal links, but they won't give you any Google Guice. (Oh, wait, Google Guice actually exists. That takes the fun out.))

Comment: @mmyers: I'll be welbogged; I never noticed that.

Comment: clarification: the URL field is unfollowed at 2k rep as a courtesy

Comment: What does that mean @JeffAtwood. Unfollowed?

Comment: @Prof.Falken: It's mentioned here: [The 'nofollow' attribute is set in user profile website link... why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55842/335251) – and explained in more detail in this MSO post: ['rel=nofollow' in Profile links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327588/1478931)

Answer (score 21):

Your profile page is yours.  You can put *pretty much* anything on there. But I wouldn't put the following:

- **Anything offensive** - *if you don't want your grandmother reading it, it probably shouldn't be on there*
- **Advertising that could be linked to spam** - The fact that you sell viagra is irrelevant on Stack Overflow, but if you provide IT consulting? That could be useful.
- **Profanity** - Generally considered 'bad form', but I don't know if anyone has had any thing other than hardcore profanity removed.
- **Offensive Gravatar images** - Some people think it's funny to see Jesus on Stack Overflow. Others do not.
- **A Wall of Text** - No one reads those. This isn't against the 'rules'; just not a smart move.

Jeff covered some basics in [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31197/why-is-the-f-word-still-allowed-in-profiles/31209#31209).

**Update**: No, Profanity isn't removed. And there are always [exceptions to the rule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog).

Comment: You know, nothing succeeds like excess! :)

Comment: You don't know Welbog's grandmother.

Comment: @Henk: I met her once.  Long story short, I couldn't eat roast beef for months afterward.

Comment: How about this profile that contains foul language in its nick name: https://askubuntu.com/users/1062493/nam-pizda?tab=topactivity in russian pronunciation? Could it be somehow penalized?

Answer (score -5):

If you have to ask, the answer is "No".

Comment: But if you have to know, the answer is "Ask".

Comment: I so want to flag this as not an answer... but it is an answer