# The 'nofollow' attribute is set in user profile website link... why?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, hyperlinks

I understand that from an SEO perspective it is beneficial for Stack Overflow to have the [`nofollow` attribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) on the website link for user profiles. Especially if people will just create an account to get a backlink.

What I think however, is that contributing members of Stack Overflow should be awarded with this backlink. I think that if someone contributes and has some decent reputation, then they should not have `nofollow` set on their website link in their user profile.

Considering the amount of users that are backlinking to Stack Overflow with flair, I really think that Stack Overflow should hook us up with some search engine love.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The nofollow on the website link is removed at 2000 reputation.

However, we do nofollow all other links in the profile as a matter of course, the same way we do in posts, comments, etc.

Comment: 2k. I must get it!

Comment: This is a nice hidden feature. Maybe add this to the FAQ for an added insentive