# Which links to user profiles on other networks are allowed?

Tags: support, profile-page

What are all the possible links that a user can have to profiles on other networks, such as LinkedIn or GitHub? I saw these two, but am not sure whether Stack Overflow allows only these or are there some other options? If someone can clarify the restriction there it could be great.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow got a Developer Story, unique to Stack Overflow, allowing users to add much more information, e.g. open source projects they're part of. For more details, please ask on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Your user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) has fields for a Twitter link, GitHub link or a generic website link:

> [image]

So you can link to *any* website, there is no restriction.

The Twitter and GitHub fields are validated so you can only enter valid usernames or links, but the generic website field isn't. As you can see, I just set the website link on my profile to the string "thisisnotawebsite" ...which is obviously not a website:

> [image]

Also, the "About me" section supports Markdown, so you can insert as many and whatever links you like there. Profiles are the least moderated content so [you can (within reason) put whatever you like in your user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31504/307988).